# $scope variable doesnot bind with view after getting updated

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have a `$scope` variable `isAuth` that is a `boolean` which will be true when user signs in. And I use this variable to show a footer using ng-hide. I have a route definition with `$routeProvider` service as well. The html code has a `maincontroller` and a subset controlled by another controller test. After a user signs in with the `login()` function of a service, I call location service to router the user to the '/test' path controlled by different controller - test. While 'test' controls only the `<ng-view>` part of the html document, the rest of the document is still with `maincontroller`. 
The issue i have is even though the value for `$isAuth` gets updated in the `servicecall()` function, it does not reflect in the html.

**Angular Code**

```
ub.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider

        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm',
            controller:'mainController'
        })

        .when('/test',{
            templateUrl: '../pages/test.htm',
            controller:'test'
        })

var ub = angular.module('ub',['ngRoute']);

ub.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','testsrv',function($scope,testsrv){
$scope.isAuth = false;
$scope.msg="";

$scope.servicecall = function(){
console.log('in service call function');

    testsrv.login().then(function(response){
  $scope.msg="in service call function";
    $scope.isAuth = true;
$location.path('/test');

    });
};//servicecall

}]);

ub.service('testsrv',['$q','$log',function($q,$log){
var self=this;
self.login = function(){
var def = $q.defer();
var msg='calling a service function';
$log.log(msg);
def.resolve(msg);
return def.promise;
};

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app='ub'>
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="servicecall()">click me!</button>
   <ng-view>
    </ng-view>
    <br>
     {{isAuth}}
    <br>
    {{msg}}

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you able to do a $scope.$apply in login()? Something like this:
` testsrv.login().then(function(response){
  $scope.msg="in service call function";
    $scope.isAuth = true;
$scope.$apply()
$location.path('/test');
    });`

Comment: ya, Tried that already and got a '$digest already in progress' error. Looks like that is not the issue

Comment: @georgeawg, that didn't solve the problem either

Comment: I solved this problem by assigning the variable to $rootScope service as $rootScope.isAuth

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by assigning the variable to $rootScope service as $rootScope.isAuth